# Using key from another object to use in a new object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying the following:

```
let foo = { a: 3, b: 4 };
let bar = { foo.a: 1, foo.b: 2 };
```

This doesn't work and to achieve this I'll have to do this:

```
let foo = { a: 3, b: 4 };

const c = foo.a;
const d = foo.b;

let bar = { c: 1, d: 2 };
```

Is there a way to do this using my first example?

Comment: BTW, the second snippett doesn't not work, right?

Comment: what you want to have, is an object like: `{ "3": 1, "4": 2}` but in your second snippet you will have `{ "c": 1, "d": 2 }`. Use computed properties as shown by @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names):

```
let bar = { [foo.a]: 1, [foo.b]: 2 };
```

**Example:**

```js
let foo = { a: 3, b: 4 };
let bar = { [foo.a]: 1, [foo.b]: 2 };

console.log(bar);
```